# subversion edge edit database directly

Tags: svn, subversion-edge

I'm running Subversion Edge 5.1.0 with Trac 1.0.9 and HT Password Manager on Redhat 7. I have a group of users outside our corporate network that is doing software development for us. They are unable to access the admin GUI to change their passwords.

All my corporate users are LDAP.  We are trying to solve an issue with our F5 firewall sending requests into the GUI. The GUI is rewriting (I think) the URL and the requests end up on port `80`  instead of `3343`.

In the meantime I've installed HT Password Manager which runs on port `80` and lets the external users change their passwords by updating the `svn_auth_file`.

I've discovered that the admin GUI is maintaining its own password file in `csvn-production-hsqldb.script`. I've updated this script manually to sync passwords but the script file gets regenerated back to the original passwords when csvn is restarted.

Also, the GUI doesn't recognize the changes I make to `csvn-production-hsqldb.script`. The information must be kept in a binary file somewhere (guessing). This has no effect on SVN itself as the users can use their new passwords to check in/check out code. Is there any way to update this database directly?

It's not a showstopper since they can't get to the GUI anyway, but in the future we may be able to solve the F5 problem and I want to be able to sync the passwords.